# Eigenvalue of $A^3$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When I read about eigenvalue, I think about a problem:

If $a$ is an eigenvalue of matrix A, then $a^3$ is the eigenvalue of $A^3$?

It is right or wrong? How to solve?

In general, how about problem with $A^n$?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_of_Matrix_Powers

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

Suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$
$$A v=\lambda v$$
Then clearly
$$A^2 v = A A v=\lambda A v=\lambda^2 v$$
and similar for $A^3$.

More generally, [functions of diagonalizable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Diagonalizable_matrices) (not just powers or polynomials) $f(A)$ can be defined as "$f(A)$ is a matrix with the same eigenvectors as $A$, but with eigenvalues $f(\lambda)$"

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to prove that $a^2$ is the eigenvalue of $A^2$. Let $v$ be the corresponding eigenvector

$$A^2v=A(Av)=A(av)=a(Av)=a(av)=a^2v$$

Hence $a^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Repeat the same procedure for other power of $A$.